# Absolutely Positioned Elements not In Place when in Actual Code

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to contain 2 images and some text to a `div`. I have it positioned the way I'd like, but when adding it to my site it's positioned in the top left corner.

How do I get it so it sits in a div by itself under the rest of my content and doesn't move to the top left of my website?

I created a fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/43qahfsn/2/

Would using percentages instead of pixels make a difference? Or is there some better way to do this?

```
#box {
width:1200px; 
height:700px;
}

.text, .stripe, .photo {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}

.text {
color:#000;
top: 50px;
left: 250px;
}

.stripe {
z-index: 1;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.photo {
top: 400px;
left: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Where's the `float`ing image? It's just positioned `absolute`ly.

Comment: For future reference, I would suggest posting a screenshot of your wireframe so that others can see exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's not a big deal but when you have `0px` you can just write it as `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the positioning of the absolutely positioned elements relative to their parent. In your case wrap them in a `div` and apply `position:relative;` to it.

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- your current html  --->
</div>
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/43qahfsn/5/

Comment: Any reason to delete the previous answer? Both seems the same.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing! Thanks for that.

Comment: @HashemQolami In the first answer I made the assumption that #box was a wrapper in OP's markup, turned out it's not.

Comment: Right, but I can see that you edited it to change `#box` to `.container`, Anyways. Both are correct.

Comment: @HashemQolami `#box` doesn't contain the absolutely positioned elements, that's why a wrapper is needed.